# Binding ObservableCollection to list

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have read multiple answers to this but simply cannot get anything to fix my problem. I have a program that receives XML from a web request in which I grab only particular attributes within that XML. When stepping through I can see that everything is working fine, the retrieval grabs the right XML, sorting through and grabbing the correct tags works, and then assigning the contents of each tag to their associated variable I have in another class works. Also When stepping through, "gridInfo" shows a list will each value that I want to display.

What I can't get to work is binding the list to a DataGrid. As you can see I create a new ObserableCollection of the class where each variable is stored and call that object. I create a list of that class and store the values from the XML to that list. Can any one help?

Also when looking at the XML I read in you will notice it's not in the normal format where everything is contained within its own opening and closing tags, this is why I have to use the DocumentElement as well as the GetElementsByTagName

**Code Behind:**

```
// This action will seach the IMDb API for the associated infromation for the IMDBID that is tagged with the title you chose in the ListBox.
     private void Movie_List_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {   // Grabs the IMDBID associated to the movie title selected to be used with the second API request.
        var p = Movie_List.SelectedIndex;

        string titleID = structholder[p].IMDBID;
        string newurl = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + titleID + "&r=XML";

        // Prepares 2nd API URL request to get data for chosen title.
        // Creates a XML Document  to store the xml data that was sent back by the API.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(newurl);

        // Creates a XML Noedlist to store the values that are going to be associated with the given attribute tag.
        XmlNodeList movieList = doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("movie");// GetElementsByTagName("root");


        ObservableCollection<Retrievalinfo> test = new       ObservableCollection<Retrievalinfo>();

        List<Retrievalinfo> gridInfo = new List<Retrievalinfo>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in movieList)
        {
          gridInfo.Add(new Retrievalinfo(){
            title = node.Attributes["title"].Value.ToString(),
            actors = node.Attributes["actors"].Value.Split(',').ToList(),
            genre = node.Attributes["genre"].Value.ToString(),
            rated = node.Attributes["rated"].Value.ToString(),
            imdbRating = node.Attributes["imdbRating"].Value.ToString(),
            released = node.Attributes["released"].Value.ToString(),
            runtime = node.Attributes["runtime"].Value.ToString(),
        });
        }

        Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = Retrievalinfo;

    }
```

**Retrivealinfo Class:**

```
namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public class Retrievalinfo
{

   public Retrievalinfo()
    {
        actors = new List<string>();
    }

    //Creating a list of info objects that will store all returned data for selected title.
   public string title { get; set; }
   public List<string> actors { get; set; }
   public string genre { get; set; }
   public string rated { get; set; }
   public string imdbRating { get; set; }
   public string released { get; set; }
   public string runtime { get; set; }
}  
}
```

XAML:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="Movie_List" ItemsSource="{Binding listInfo}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="287" Margin="20,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="198" SelectionChanged="Movie_List_SelectionChanged" />
        <Label Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Movie List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="70,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Cooper Black" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="Movie_DataGrid" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="232,107,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="198" Width="497" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding gridInfo}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=title}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Main Actor 1" Binding="{Binding Path=actors[0]}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Main Actor 2" Binding="{Binding Path=actors[1]}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Main Actor 3" Binding="{Binding Path=actor[2]}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Genre" Binding="{Binding Path=genre}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rated" Binding="{Binding Path=rated}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="IMDB Rating" Binding="{Binding Path=imdbRating}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Released" Binding="{Binding Path=released}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Runtime" Binding="{Binding Path=runtime}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

XML I Read In:

```
<root response="True">
<movie title="Up in the Air" year="2009" rated="R" released="23 Dec 2009" runtime="109 
min" genre="Drama, Romance" director="Jason Reitman" writer="Walter Kirn (novel), Jason
Reitman (screenplay), Sheldon Turner (screenplay)" actors="George Clooney, Vera Farmiga,
Anna Kendrick, Jason Bateman" plot="With a job that has him traveling around the country
firing people, Ryan Bingham leads an empty life out of a suitcase, until his company
does the unexpected: ground him." language="English" country="USA" awards="Nominated for
6 Oscars. Another 64 wins & 66      nominations."poster="http://ia.mediaimdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI3MzYxMTA4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMD
E4ODg3Mg@@._V1_SX300.jpg" metascore="83" imdbRating="7.5" imdbVotes="215,961"   imdbID="tt1193138" type="movie"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = Retrievalinfo;   Retrievalinfo is a class not a collection.  I am surprised that compiles.  Try Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = gridInfo;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the xml you provided is perfectly formed (the fact the element doesn't have a closing tag - is OK... a tag which ends with `/>` (ie: `<bla attributeName='value' />`) is considered closed, and does not need a closing tag.

Second - why not using linq to xml?? it would make the code simpler and more readable:

```
    // Prepares 2nd API URL request to get data for chosen title.
    // Creates a XML Document  to store the xml data that was sent back by the API.
    var doc = XElement.Load(newurl);

    // Creates a XML Noedlist to store the values that are going to be associated with the given attribute tag.
    IEnumerable<XElement> movieList = doc.Descendants("movie");


    ObservableCollection<Retrievalinfo> gridInfo = new ObservableCollection<Retrievalinfo>(movieList.Select(movieElement =>
        new Retrievalinfo()
        {
            title = movieElement.Attribute("title").Value,
            actors = movieElement.Attribute("actors").Value.Split(',').ToList(),
            genre = movieElement.Attribute("genre").Value,
            rated = movieElement.Attribute("rated").Value,
            imdbRating = movieElement.Attribute("imdbRating").Value,
            released = movieElement.Attribute("released").Value,
            runtime = movieElement.Attribute("runtime").Value,
        }));
```

and lastly - you misunderstood why using ObservableCollection in the first place.
First, to bind the data - just bind the list itself.

```
Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = gridInfo;
```

When you want the control to show any change made on the list (any addition, removal, etc), without rebinding it (which means reloading it entirely), user ObservableCollection. Otherwise, you can use any sequence of items (ie, any type which implement IEnumerable).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on linq to xml. Is that just the properties you are using like XElement, IEnumerable, ect. Also what I was trying to say about the xml is that, in previous questions and answers I looked at most people were using xml that was saved to a file and wanted all information stored between an opening and closing tag, thus GetElementsByTagName worked for them but not me.

Comment: Also in your ObserableCollection line, movielist.Select....Does not provide an option for "movieElement". Also, after that sequence "movieElement =>" does not have a closing ) unless the "new Retrievalinfo()" is apart of that line. Are you able to look over your code again?

Comment: About LINQ to xml - google it! 
It's much simpler and friendly than DOMXml. 
About select - what you see is lambda expression, and it's a way to write anonymous methods. 
The anonymous method is getting one parameter (movieElement, which its type is inferred by the compiler to be XElement), and return new RetrieveInfo (which is indeed part of the command).

Comment: Ok. The only thing with the lambda expression is that it errors out and I can't compile. Ive never worked with these so i dont know the slightest way to troubleshoot it. Should it not have a closing parentheses? the only thing that errors out is the new ObserableCollection and then the movieElement parameter in assigning a value to the associated variable (movie.Element.Attributes('title')....) Any recomendations?

Comment: Well, it's looking fine (from my cell phone)... It won't work on c#2.0 and below (which means you need visual studio 2008 or above), and, you should have `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file (where the other using statements) - otherwise the compiler won't recognize the Select method... I hope it will resolve your problem

Comment: Another question for you, Would you like to give some hints as how the XAML should be set up. Is the Binding correct? Binding on the author list? Do I have to declare each column header like I have or will they auto populate?

Comment: My experience with WPF is limited.. If I remember correctly - you actually need to declare the header, but I might be wrong here... So - test it... check if the grid view is populated with columns if you omit the column declaration. But, I recommend you to change the properties' types of `Retrievalinfo` to they appropriate types (ie, make the `released` property datetime instead of string). One beautiful thing about LINQ to XML is that you can simply cast the attribute to the wanted type: `released = (DateTime)movieElement.Attribute("released"),`

Answer (score 0):

First of all;

*What I can't get to work is binding the list to a DataGrid*

Binding to a `List` is totally accepted and you can do it. However, you would have to manage your own PropertyChanged Events. That is why we have the ObservableCollection class. When you bind the ItemSource of any controls to an ObservableCollection , the View is automatocaly notified when something changes into it (add/delete/modify, **Not instantiated again**). So you should use an ObservableCollection.

Secondo;

I see you declare your gridInfo inside the method `Movie_List_SelectionChanged` which is not good because the xaml Binding mechanics will search for a **Property** in your **DataContext**. The xaml won't find gridInfo there. Declare your property in your class like this in your dataContext:

```
public ObservableCollection<Retrievalinfo> gridInfo { get; set; }
```

dont Forget to instantiate it in the constructor of your DataContext. And also don't forget to declare your DataContext in the Code Behind of your xaml.

Lastly, you already declared your ItemSource in your xaml (`ItemsSource="{Binding gridInfo}"`), so no need to do it again in your code behind (`Movie_DataGrid.ItemsSource = Retrievalinfo;`).

**--EDIT--**
Due to your comment, I will try to clarify things up a bit for you. a classic design would have 3 things:

- XAML file, your view, where and how your informations will be displayed.
- Your code behind (the .xaml.cs file) in which you will declare your DataContext.
- Your DataContext. It is the the .cs where you will have the properties to which you will bind in your XAML.

In your situation. You have your XAML, which is not totally correct by the way (you can't say to bind on actor[0].. you need to use an itemControl inside your datagrid to generate those column. I would suggest to try some tutorial on the web. There is plenty of easy tuto for you to improve your understanding of WPF.

To continue, you also have your code behind, in the constructor of your conde behind, normally, you should only set your Datacontext. Something like this:

```
DataContext = new MyDataContext();
```

Then, finally, in your DataContext, you should have a declaration of the properties you bind to in your xaml and instantiate them in the constructor. You can also call methods to fetch your infomartions from any database (**which methods will also be in the DataContext**. According to the MVVM design pattern, the View should not communicate with the Model).

Hope this helped you.

Comment: Do you mean in my Retreivalinfo class where my variables are stored. You mention DataContext, does that mean I would need to declare it in the XMAL?

Comment: Edited my answer, please reconsider reading it, hope it'll help.

Comment: Yes I knew the binding on the list was off, thats just so I remember that I have more than one value. Also this helps. but another question. Is my Retivealinfo class working like a DataContext? or no?

Comment: No. It is a "dataObject" that you use to store informations. They are meant to be contained in an ObservableCollection in your dataContext.

Comment: Actually the Binding on [0] works, it might not be the best method of doing so but it does work